# Prepared statements with variable columns

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am creating a database for a game that I have been working on and I need the users to be able to kill each other, so I have set up the table like this:

```
...
`alive1` => Player 1's status
`alive2` => Player 2's status
`alive3` => Player 3's status
`alive4` => Player 4's status
...
```

I need to be able to modify these columns in the database on a per-case basis, and with input directly from the user. However, doing something like this:

```
$stmt = $link->prepare("UPDATE `games` SET `alive{$_GET["player"]}`=0 WHERE `id`=?")
```

is vulnerable to SQL injection. Is there a good way to "bind" the column name to the query so that I can modify the table safely?

Proper input for $_GET["player"] should just be an integer 1..4, so I guess I could check the input directly if need be and make sure that it is one of those four possibilities, but I was hoping that there would be a more elegant solution. This may arise again later in a different project where the set of possible inputs would be much larger, and hard-coding each case would be very time-consuming.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identifiers cannot be bound into the prepared statement hence you should whitelist them.

In general for whitelisting you create an array of valid identifiers and check if the passed one is in the list. Eg:

```
$validColumns = array('alive1', 'alive2', 'alive3', 'alive4');
$col = 'alive' . $_GET["player"];
$isSafeToUse = in_array($col, $validColumns);
```

In your case you can just

```
$id = (int)$_GET["player"];
```

and check then that `$id` is in the `[1, 4]` range.

Comment: I see, so I would just do something like `if($id > 0 and $id < 5) //do statement`?

Comment: @MathNerdProductions Yep. I'd go with `$id >= 1 && $id <= 4` though.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a reguar expression `/^[1-4]$/`

```
if(preg_match('/^[1-4]$/', $_GET['player'])){
    $stmt = $link->prepare('UPDATE `games` SET `alive' . $_GET['player'] . '` =0 WHERE `id`=?');
} else {
    die;
}
```

To use this for future projects you could expand this to  `/^[0-9]{1,3}$/`, that would allow you to accept a number up to `999`

Comment: @zerkms I was using that so that he can expand on it in the future say `/^[0-9]{1,3}$/`

Comment: No point to overcomplicate solutions without reason. When one needs that - they can do that.